# How do I add python into html?

Tags: python, html

I was just wondering how to add python into html. I am wanting two ways:

- Using the form method (`<form for=“name” action=“action.py”><button type=“Submit”></button></form>`)
- Without the form method (`<!-- No <form> tags -->`)

Comment: I think browsers can only understand javascript so that might not work. Unless something compiles that python into javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Flask, as it will allow you to get rid of all the JS, and only use Python. Flask is a microframework.

Comment: Oops, I realized I made a mistake. My bad, my apologies.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant add python into html.

Comment: flask allows you to import python functions and use them

Comment: Are you talking about importing python to html? or are you talking about importing python to javascript?

Comment: python to HTML directly

Comment: I don’t really understand what you mean.

Comment: you write python code, then use the built-in Jinja to add the functions to the HTML and use their output.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand now.